# Does Bootstrap CSS override theme?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Over the past few years, I have worked with many WordPress theme templates. I have now decided to take the next step of learning to create my own WordPress themes.

I am now at the stage whereby I am looking to use the Bootstrap feature, in order to make my website responsive. I understand how to transfer files from the Bootstrap website and place them on my server, however I am at a loss on how they work with my website. Here area few questions:

1. I have already created a '[theme-name].css' to style my website. Will the Bootstrap CSS file automatically override my theme CSS file (s)?
2. When I transfer the Bootstrap files to my server, do I simply add the contents of my own stylesheet, the Bootstrap CSS file or call both CSS files together using the 'function.php' file?
3. When I transfer the Bootstrap files to my server, do I have to rename any of the files?
4. At present, I am currently calling my stylesheets, by inserting the following code in my 'functions.php' file:

   ```
   function [theme-name]_script_enqueue() {

   wp_enqueue_style('customstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/[theme-name].css', array(), '1.0', 'all');

   wp_enqueue_script('customjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/[theme-name].js', array(), '1.0', true);
   }

   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', '[theme-name]script_enqueue' );
   ```

Referring to the above code, would I need to change the code to reflect the Bootstrap.css files or simply add another function for the Bootstrap files, so that they can both be called?

Apologies if my questions are using incorrect terminologies, as the Bootstrap functionality is a new set of files to me.

Comment: *"Does Bootstrap CSS override theme?"* - Unless you override rules with `!important` then yeah, it most likely will. Write your own css file/rules and add it to your head tags.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Are you saying that if I 'attach' '!important' to a particular CSS input, that will be the overriding code, regardless of the file hierarchy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just add another call to load the bootstrap css. Make sure you add bootstrap before your custom CSS.

See below

https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/customize-bootstrap/

You shouldnt need to rename any files providing you link them correctly in your function call.